# Azure WebRole MVC4 installation issue

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy an ASP .NET MVC4 application to Windows Azure, I have a startup task which installs 
MVC4. But my role is not coming online, the deployment status is:

Wating for Role to start...System start up tasks are running

Sites were deployed...

Recovering...

Wating for Role to start...System start up tasks are running

Sites were deployed...

Recovering...

Wating for Role to start...System start up tasks are running

Sites were deployed...

Recovering...

This is keep on happening.

Another intersting thing i noticed is if i RDP into the Role instance then the role become ready state..

Any one has an idea, whats going wrong here?

Thanks 
Anu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, the issue was the permission of the user ( i think its 'system') who runs the start-up task to  install MVC4. I have updated my start-up script (installmvc4-main.cmd) to do the following:

1. Creates another script 'installmvc4-impl.cmd' which invokes the a power shell script 'installmvc4.ps1' with execution policy set to unrestricted.
2. Creates a powershell script 'installmvc4.ps1' to install mvc4 using the installer included   in the package (I downloaded it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683)
3. Creates a user, add it to administrator group and schedule a task to run 'installmvc4-impl.cmd' using this user.

Here the script 'installmvc4-main.cmd':

```
REM Create dos script installmvc4-impl.cmd to invoke the powershell script to install MVC4

echo if "%%EMULATED%%"=="true" goto :EOF > %~dp0installmvc4-impl.cmd
echo powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted %~dp0installmvc4.ps1 ^> installmvc4.ps1.log 2^>^&1 >> %~dp0\installmvc4-impl.cmd
echo exit ^/B 0 >> %~dp0installmvc4-impl.cmd

REM Create the powershell script installmvc4.ps1 to install MVC4

echo Invoke-Expression "%~dp0AspNetMVC4Setup.exe /q /norestart" > %~dp0installmvc4.ps1

REM Create an admin user and schedule task using this user to run the script that install MVC4

net user anuchandy Admin!@#123 /add
net localgroup Administrators aunchandy /add
schtasks /CREATE /TN "install-mvc4-task" /SC ONCE /SD 01/01/2020 /ST 00:00:00 /RL HIGHEST /RU anuchandy /RP Admin!@#123 /TR "%~dp0\installmvc4-impl.cmd" /F
schtasks /RUN /TN "install-mvc4-task"
```

Note: Make sure the character encoding of the srartup task installmvc4-main.cmd is ANSI.

Comment: You do not need to run an installer for MVC4. You only need to mark the references as CopyLocal=true in your project. This was done by the mvc3 web role project template before mvc3 was available on the os image.

Answer (score 2):

As Sandrino mentioned, startup tasks can cause this. Whenever I see that pattern, it seems that most of the time I have assemblies referenced that are on on the Azure VM that I am being deployed to.

There is a tool out there: http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/ that will compare assemblies in your csproj file with the current Azure OS version to locate any assemblies that will need to be marked as CopyLocal=true. Note that this tool is looking at osfamily=2. VS defaults to creating osfamily=1 in your cscfg file.

This seems highly likely to me since you are deploying an MVC 4 project probably with a version of EntityFramework that is not on the Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a startup task which is causing problems or because of your web application not working correctly. Since the diagnostics module can take a few minutes to send the logs to your storage account I suggest you connect through RDP and take a look in the Event Viewer (under Application) to see what's happening (look for errors and warnings).

Answer (score 0):

Your startup script file should have EXIT /B 0 command in the end.